# Is $f_B:X_B\to \operatorname{Spec}B$ separated?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, noetherian

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme. Given two morphisms of schemes $f: X\to \operatorname{Spec}A$ and $\pi: \operatorname{Spec}B\to\operatorname{Spec}A$, if $\pi$ is flat, is $f_B:X_B\to \operatorname{Spec}B$ separated?

Comment: Every morphism of affines is separated, and separatedness is stable under base change. Flatness is unnecessary.

Comment: As stated this is surely false no? Consider any nonseparated $X \to \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ and take $\pi : \mathrm{Spec}(k) \to \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ the identity.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation of my comment.

(1) Every morphism of affine schemes is separated.

First, recall that the diagonal $\Delta: Spec(B) \rightarrow Spec(B \otimes_{A} B)$ is given by the multiplication map $m:B \otimes_{A} B \rightarrow B$ which is surjective. By the surjectivity of $m$, we know that $V(ker(m)) \simeq Spec(B \otimes_{A} B / ker(m)) \simeq Spec(B)$ via $\Delta$. Furthermore, the surjectivity of $m$ tells us that the morphism of structure sheaves $\mathscr{O}_{Spec(B \otimes_{A} B)} \rightarrow \Delta_{\ast}\mathscr{O}_{Spec(B)}$ is surjective as well. Thus, $\Delta$ is a closed immersion.

(2) The base change of a separated morphism is separated.

Suppose we have morphisms $X \rightarrow S$ and $Z \rightarrow S$, and that $X \rightarrow S$ is separated. We would like to show that $X' = X \times_{S} Z \rightarrow Z$ is separated as well. To do so, simply observe that

$$ \Delta : X \times_{S} Z \rightarrow (X \times_{S} Z) \times_{Z} (X \times_{S} Z) \simeq (X \times_{S} X) \times_{S} Z $$

is just the base change of the closed immersion $X \rightarrow X \times_{S} X$. Since closed immersions are stable under base change, we are done. A proof that closed immersions are stable under base change involves making categorical arguments using pullback squares; a nice proof by Zhen Lin is given here [Separated scheme stable under base extension.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277445/separated-scheme-stable-under-base-extension)

Comment: I don't say $X$ is affine, is $\pi$ separated?

Comment: $\pi$ is a morphism of affines, hence automatically separated. Furthermore, based on how you've written the problem $\pi$ has nothing to do with $X$ being affine or non-affine.

Comment: I make a mistake, I wanna ask "Is $f$ separated".

Comment: That is what I proved in my answer. As a byproduct of the proof that $f$ is separated, we find that $\pi$ is separated as well. In fact, we USE the separatedness of $\pi$ to prove that $f$ is separated.

Comment: Can you show that any morphism from  a Noetherian scheme to an affine scheme is separated? I need the details.

Comment: Let $X$ be the affine line over a field $k$ with the origin doubled. Then $X \rightarrow Spec(k)$ is not separated. See Hartshorne Chapter II Examples 2.3.6 and 4.0.2.